# How to remove balloon/ripple effect while entering pin on lock screen?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Recently I updated my phone to android lollipop. When I type my pin in lock screen a balloon/ripple effect or a circular thing is observed near the key which I pressed/touched. I don't want that effect in my mobile. Can I remove it without rooting my phone?

Comment: Do you mean the ripple effect ?

Comment: yes, I guess that is what it is called technically. Added it to my question :)

Comment: That is a doubt, because it is present in the device's framework. You can't remove it unless you modify it, and you can't modify it unless you root your phone. So ... You can't without rooting.

Comment: huh :| I wanted it to be removed so that my screen lock is bit more safe. I mean when I type a key others can see the ripple effect and guess the password. Ripple effect it making my pin less secure :(

Comment: Well, if you want safety, you can root your phone, install Xposed, and search for randomized pin lock or something. So, if your keypad is like 123 456 789 0 , that will make it like 681 294 375 0 . That would be extreme security, because the layout randomizes each time. Nobody can guess it.

Comment: Or you could use other modules, which allow the creation of 9x9 grid squares for pattern lock, and things like that.

Comment: But, rooting is a must for the above methods. Rooting, and Installing Xposed framework, and then doing so. Moreover, with Xposed, I think you can disable that Ripple effect too, with a module like Monster UI or something.

Comment: Ok.. Will give it a try. Thanks for your the help :)

Comment: @rjt.rockx May I suggest the strong warning against Xposed framework for Lollipop. Its alpha release and its known to cause boot loops and other issues. I consider myself lucky, so I didn't had one in my lollipop. OP here might miss such warning on Xposed framework or could ignore such in a hurry to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Firelord only on some devices. I have been following rovo89's Xposed Framework for Lollipop on XDA, and some manual fixes have been released for prevention of Bootloops. You can look there and use them if you want to. But, thanks for mentioning it. // Abhishek, sorry, I forgot to mention that. What Firelord is saying is right, so be careful. REALLY CAREFUL. Xposed for Lollipop is still in Alpha, so, if you don't know your way around a bootloop, I'd strongly dis-recommend it.

Comment: got it! Thanks.. Will make sure I read all the instructions carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

Without rooting there are 2 ways at least. Neither are that great, but they do produce the desired behaviour.

## Developer Settings

1. Activate developer settings by tapping the build number 7 times
2. Adjust the animation speed (Animator Duration Scale). Either make it much faster or disable it completely

This has the downside of disabling all the lovely material design animations universally :/ Fortunately, transitions can still be preserved so it isn't all that terrible.

## Power-Saving Mode

This is essentially toggling power saving mode as required because this too will disable the lockscreen ripple animation. Whilst it also disables all animations, this may be preferable as it's easier to toggle (fewer taps) than digging into developer settings.

## Rooting

Rooting and installation of xposed for Lollipop is of course much more preferable, and opens up many more options, but without that, you still have the above two options.

Comment: Power-saving and developer settings options didn't worked :|

Comment: The circle will still appear, but it should appear instantly (not with the grow and fade out)

Comment: oh..k. So, there is no way to  remove circle without rooting?

Comment: I believe so. Wouldn't your finger generally be obscuring the circle in any case?

Comment: They will, but when I move to next key the circle doesn't disappear fast. :|

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked if it can be done **without** root. I don't think that's possible. I tried creating a theme for cm12 that would disable the ripple system-wide but it seems "ripple_material_light" and "ripple_material_dark" is ignored in android/res/values/colors.xml (works fine when set directly for each app, that definitely is possible).

Instead I have created a simple patch to disable the ripple effect altogether (but it requires root): https://github.com/luv/android5_noripple